# Kubuntu 18.04: Desktop icon label text replaced by blocks of colored snow

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, fonts

After my Kubuntu 18.04.3 LTS PC wakes from sleep mode, desktop icon text is replaced with blocks of colored snow.

I don't know if this happened because I didn't create a swap partition during Kubuntu installation. I must restart or switch user to bring things back to normal.

[image: Desktop showing colored snow instead of icon labels]